# Load xml from string that contains HTML

Tags: c#, load, xmldocument

I am doing the following -

```
        // Create message
        StringBuilder sbXML = new StringBuilder();
        sbXML .Append("<root>");
        sbXML .AppendFormat("<messageBody>{0}</messageBody>", JsonString);          
        sbXML .Append("</root>");
```

Where `JsonString` is a json string, however some of the entries in the json are strings of html (which I think this is why it is breaking).

When I do -

```
        XmlDocument xmlDOC = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDOC.LoadXml(sbXML.ToString());
```

I get the error -

```
'\' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''.
```

My Json also contains urls so for instance -

```
{
    "exampleJson": {
        "url":  "http://example.com/",
        "html": "<a href=\"http://example.com\" rel=\"test\">example text</a>"
    }
}
```

I believe it is these values that is leading to the exception, is there a way around this so that `xmlDOC.LoadXml` can load my Json, I considered doing something like -

```
xmlDOC.LoadXml(sbXML.ToString().Replace("character to replace", "acceptable character"));
```

However this is obviously not ideal. I also tried just using

```
.Load
```

However this resulted in illegal characters in the path exception.

Comment: Please explain why you must construct XML with string concatenation. Using any of XML APIs to build XML would give you code that works instead of attempting broken workarounds like suggested CDATA.

Comment: @maccettura `{"foo": "Haha]]> good luck adding me as CDATA}</messageBody>"}`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I completely misread the question.  I thought that OP had already extracted the HTML from the property, not that they were adding the _entire_ JSON string to the XML

Comment: @maccettura Indeed HTML inside JSON *never ever* contains `]]>`... because JSON makes everything better :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to be doing something like:

```
        StringBuilder sbXML = new StringBuilder();
        sbXML.Append("<root>");
        sbXML.Append("<messageBody />");
        sbXML.Append("</root>");

        XmlDocument xmlDOC = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDOC.LoadXml(sbXML.ToString());
        xmlDOC.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("messageBody").InnerText = JsonString;
```

As pointed out by @Alexei Levenkov creating Xml by string concatenation is a really bad idea and will lead to more problems later.

Using the System.Xml.XmlDocument methods is a much safer method that will encode all the bits it needs to to make the value of `JsonString` Xml safe.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) tag.

example:

```
<messageBody><![CDATA[ any json data  ]]> </messageBody>
```